# Error in 'appendListItem' - google addons

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-developer-tools

I'm trying to copy listItem from one google doc to others.

**Here is the code:**

```
  var activeDocID=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  var targetBody = DocumentApp.openById(activeDocID).getBody();

  for (i = 0; i < docCopy.getBody().getNumChildren(); i++) 
  {

    var element =docCopy.getBody().getChild(i).copy();
    var type = element.getType();

    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) 
    {
         if (element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() != 0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) 
         {
           var blob = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();    
           targetBody.appendImage(blob);
         }
         else 
           targetBody.appendParagraph(element.asParagraph());
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      targetBody.appendTable(element);
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
      var image = element.asInlineImage().getBlob();    
      targetBody.appendImage(image);
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      targetBody.appendListItem(element);
    }

    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE) {
      targetBody.appendHorizontalRule();
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK) {
      targetBody.appendPageBreak();
    }
  }
```

and I get the error:

> "Service unavailable: Documents" (השירות לא זמין: מסמכים)

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the value of `element` when the error is being thrown?

Comment: the element is ListItem with image. if I delete the image from the source it's work ok.

Comment: Can you please share its value? There isn't enough information here to know why this error is being thrown as it could be for many different reasons.

Comment: How can I see its value?

Comment: Put it in a log, either `Logger.log()` or `console.log()` and view it in the regular or stackdriver logs.

Comment: I did it, but if I use "Logger.log(element.asListItem())", its print: "ListItem", and "Logger.log(element.asListItem().getText)" its print the text value.

Comment: Please log `.getType()` - ther is not enough information here to understand where the issue lies.

Comment: .getType() = ListItem. I see that "targetBody.appendImage(blob);" return the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the sample Document for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.